# Print full bibliography citation entries in text (optex iso style)

Tags: bibliographies, optex

Sometimes it is nice to print the full reference "on the spot", instead of in a reference section, like the `fullcite` command (or the verbose style) in biblatex:

`\fullcite[knuth]` --> Knuth, Donald Ervin. *The Tex Book.* ... etc.

The printing of a "References" section in the end should be optional.

Is that possible using `optex`?

Perhaps a MWE could be like:

```
\fontfam[Termes]
\nonumcitations

\fullcite[optextug] % full cites
\cite[optextug] --- \rcite[optextug] % regular author-date
\nocite[*]
\usebib/s (iso690) op-biblist % printing optional
\end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a solution in [OpTeX tricks and tips section](http://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#fullcite). You can copy and paste their code and use their fullcite command (as well as readbib)